# How to find which today's time series value is relatively more different?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, similarities, anomaly-detection

I have 130 times series, each present daily average price of a stock till today,
They have very very similar behaviour in terms of trends, peaks, minimums .... just the level are different (y value).

I want to build a model to find the relative cheapest and richest stock that have been traded **today**. So in fact it is like finding anomalies (if there is any today).
I think comparing change of today price with the median price last 210 days can be useful. But I look for more advance and robust methods.

Any idea how I can do it? Statistical method or AI method?